# Migrating back from MongoDB to ActiveRecord in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, activerecord, devise, database-migration

When I migrated my MongoDB database back to a simple SQL database, I received some errors, mainly:

```
uninitialized constant BSON [NameError]
```

and

```
Cannot visit BSON::ObjectId
```

I followed [this](http://denmarkin.tumblr.com/post/4475718721/jump-back-from-mongoid-to-activerecord) guide to perform my migration.

Any clue?

-frbl

Answer (score 2):

It took me some hours to figure out, but it seemed to be extremely simple. These are all steps I took. Note that this application did not contain any valuable information, so destroying everything was not an issue for me.

Remove all devise stuff (model, initializer, routes and views like described [here](http://denmarkin.tumblr.com/post/4475718721/jump-back-from-mongoid-to-activerecord)
Set the basic ORM models back to ActiveModels:

code:

```
config.generators do |g|
   g.orm :active_record
end
```

Re-install devise:

```
rails g devise:install
rails g devise user
rake db:migrate
```

now everything is set up, but the most important point, remove your session!! What I dit was changing the secret code in config/initializers/secret_token.rb (according to [this](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2404) guide)

Took me 3 hours, so I hope it saves you some time.

-frbl

Comment: Yeah, what if you couldn't destroy all things?

Comment: Great answer. Changing the secret code in config/initializers/secret_token.rb was the secret to me.